# tyring to sync ropsten testnet with android-inproc: Rolled back 2 headers

Tags: go-ethereum, testnets, android, ropsten

I am trying to sync the new testnet with the android inproc node ( tried with geth-1.5.3, geth-1.5.4-SNAPSHOT and geth-1.5.5-SNAPSHOT )

getting this log:

```
11-28 20:00:29.957  6637  6861 E GoLog   : I1128 19:00:29.957392 node/node.go:175] instance: GethDroid/android/go1.7
11-28 20:00:29.957  6637  6861 E GoLog   : I1128 19:00:29.957527 ethdb/database.go:83] Allotted 16MB cache and 16 file handles to /data/user/0/org.ligi.ewallet/files/.ethereum42/GethDroid/lightchaindata
11-28 20:00:29.982  6637  6861 E GoLog   : I1128 19:00:29.982051 eth/backend.go:282] Successfully wrote custom genesis block: 41941023680923e0fe4d74a34bdac8141f2540e3ae90623718e47d66d1ca4a2d
11-28 20:00:29.982  6637  6861 E GoLog   : I1128 19:00:29.982467 light/lightchain.go:172] Last header: #0 [41941023…] TD=1048576
11-28 20:00:29.982  6637  6861 E GoLog   : I1128 19:00:29.982707 light/lightchain.go:172] Last header: #0 [41941023…] TD=1048576
11-28 20:00:29.982  6637  6861 E GoLog   : I1128 19:00:29.982897 p2p/server.go:336] Starting Server
11-28 20:00:29.995  6637  6865 E GoLog   : I1128 19:00:29.995718 les/backend.go:196] WARNING: light client mode is an experimental feature
11-28 20:00:29.995  6637  6865 E GoLog   : I1128 19:00:29.995722 p2p/server.go:604] Listening on [::]:60838
11-28 20:00:32.978  6637  6868 E GoLog   : I1128 19:00:32.978346 les/handler.go:253] Found LES server: enode://6e269245780baa8eaf6f033617ede997a2a9df0eed0e4138988b9d9c1bd63f1ad8e0cb7929285bc72e0badf00bf14670561001788e51f915637281b49488eb51@54.236.215.120:30303
11-28 20:00:33.640  6637  6868 E GoLog   : I1128 19:00:33.640186 eth/downloader/downloader.go:326] Block synchronisation started
11-28 20:00:45.141  6637  6868 E GoLog   : I1128 19:00:45.140997 les/handler.go:253] Found LES server: enode://b70fb61a041c3f6cbe73ebdddb2816e04c4297aa4c5a5881cf3ebd24c0bd1bdb5d3c2d3e124ebab4af1144acbba4d9881bce767c6dbdbe31583aadb7da9c03f8@94.242.229.4:30303
11-28 20:01:56.779  6637  6868 E GoLog   : I1128 19:01:56.779542 eth/downloader/downloader.go:1198] Rolled back 2 headers (LH: 0->0, FB: 0->0, LB: 0->0)
11-28 20:04:38.641  6637  6868 E GoLog   : I1128 19:04:38.641719 eth/downloader/downloader.go:1198] Rolled back 1 headers (LH: 0->0, FB: 0->0, LB: 0->0)
11-28 20:08:07.155  6637  6868 E GoLog   : I1128 19:08:07.154881 eth/downloader/downloader.go:1198] Rolled back 1 headers (LH: 0->0, FB: 0->0, LB: 0->0)
11-28 20:08:16.872  6637  6868 E GoLog   : I1128 19:08:16.872549 eth/downloader/downloader.go:1198] Rolled back 1 headers (LH: 0->0, FB: 0->0, LB: 0->0)
11-28 20:10:20.688  6637  6868 E GoLog   : I1128 19:10:20.688442 eth/downloader/downloader.go:1198] Rolled back 1 headers (LH: 0->0, FB: 0->0, LB: 0->0)
11-28 20:13:39.210  6637  6868 E GoLog   : I1128 19:13:39.210323 eth/downloader/downloader.go:1198] Rolled back 1 headers (LH: 0->0, FB: 0->0, LB: 0->0)
11-28 20:14:36.848  6637  6868 E GoLog   : I1128 19:14:36.848824 eth/downloader/downloader.go:1198] Rolled back 1 headers (LH: 0->0, FB: 0->0, LB: 0->0)
11-28 20:16:42.030  6637  6868 E GoLog   : I1128 19:16:41.986015 eth/downloader/downloader.go:1198] Rolled back 1 headers (LH: 0->0, FB: 0->0, LB: 0->0)
11-28 20:18:59.676  6637  6868 E GoLog   : I1128 19:18:59.675763 eth/downloader/downloader.go:1198] Rolled back 1 headers (LH: 0->0, FB: 0->0, LB: 0->0)
11-28 20:20:15.307  6637  6868 E GoLog   : I1128 19:20:15.306734 eth/downloader/downloader.go:1198] Rolled back 1 headers (LH: 0->0, FB: 0->0, LB: 0->0)
11-28 20:21:14.925  6637  6868 E GoLog   : I1128 19:21:14.925196 eth/downloader/downloader.go:1198] Rolled back 1 headers (LH: 0->0, FB: 0->0, LB: 0->0)
11-28 20:21:20.580  6637  6868 E GoLog   : I1128 19:21:20.580626 eth/downloader/downloader.go:1198] Rolled back 1 headers (LH: 0->0, FB: 0->0, LB: 0->0)
```

I am seeing the right block-height of ropsten and I connect to 2..3 peers - unfortunately currentblock sticks at 0 - no matter how long I wait